# Cannot open android studio on ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-20.04

I have the android-studio folder, but when I run ./studio.sh I get the following error:

```
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true

Startup Error
Unable to detect graphics environment
```

I have ensured that I have java installed, and I have tried running the terminal as administrator and opening a new one. I have also tried installing Xming and running xeyes and that doesn't work either.